# How to append all status codes to one list?

Tags: python, regex, list

I want to add each error status in a list and after that visualize them with matplotlib or something else. The problem is that when I try to this it creates a separate list for each 404 code for example. How can I append all 404 errors in one list?

I want to be like this:

```
error_codes = ['404', '404, '404, ...]
```

My code:

```
import re

with open('./access_tail.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

for line in data:
    pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)).*((?:200|3[0][0-4]|4[0][0-4]|5[0][0-7]))')

    for (ip, date, status) in re.findall(pattern, line):
        print(ip, status, date)

    list = []
    if '404' in status:
        list.append(status)
        print(list)
```

My output:

```
193.27.228.27 404 10:24:03
['404']
189.39.247.86 403 11:04:06
193.27.228.27 404 11:29:47
['404']
117.222.59.231 403 13:23:47
123.234.86.215 404 13:57:15
['404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:05:23
['404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:05:23
['404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:05:24
['404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:19:11
['404']
193.118.53.202 403 14:36:41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```py
import re

with open('./access_tail.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*((?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d):(?:[0-5]\d)).*((?:200|3[0][0-4]|4[0][0-4]|5[0][0-7]))')

list = []

for line in data:
    for (ip, date, status) in re.findall(pattern, line):
        if '404' in status:
            print(ip, status, date)
            list.append(status)

print(list)
```

Comment: i tried your code it some how helps but it appends list per line :
193.27.228.27 404 10:24:03
['404']
189.39.247.86 403 11:04:06
193.27.228.27 404 11:29:47
['404', '404']
117.222.59.231 403 13:23:47
123.234.86.215 404 13:57:15
['404', '404', '404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:05:23
['404', '404', '404', '404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:05:23
['404', '404', '404', '404', '404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:05:24
['404', '404', '404', '404', '404', '404']
23.98.152.191 404 14:19:11
['404', '404', '404', '404', '404', '404', '404']
193.118.53.202 403 14:36:41

Comment: wdym by appends list per line? Can you post a picture? You can't format your output on Stack Oerflow comment box I think.

Comment: i`m loocking for a way to send you a picture :)

Comment: Just post it on imgur and send the link. @ImanAshoori

Comment: just the last line as i described in my question

Comment: I updated it. Let me know if that is something you want. @ImanAshoori

Comment: thx ava :-D you reallu helped me just now . I am really grateful :))

Comment: @ImanAshoori if this helped you, you can mark as accepted. :)